# Query for checking combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have a table called rule which has the following columns and values

**rules**

| rule_id | entity_name | entity_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | true |
| 2 | abc | false |
| 3 | xyz | true |

I have another table with values as below

**all_values**

| id | entity_name | entity_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | abc | true |
| 100 | abc | false |
| 100 | xyz | true |
| 101 | abc | true |
| 102 | abc | false |
| 102 | abc | true |

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/86e5ef).

Now what I want to do is I need to find the *least common factor* from `all_values` table based on the `rules` table.

For eg. Given a `rules` table with values as above I need to check the `all_values` table to see what combinations in table `all_values` will give me the values of the `rules` table. In the above example I will get the result as below

| combination_id | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 101 |
| 2 | 102 |

or preferrably output as

| combination_id | json |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {id:[100]} |
| 2 | {id{[101,102]} |

I do not want the additional combination of 100,101,102 or 100,102 as it would be a duplicate.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? (I'm asking because there are some new features in SQL Server 2022 that might be useful here, such as `GENERATE_SERIES`)

Comment: What is the datatype of the `rules.entity_value` column? Can you share your `CREATE TABLE` statements? Why is the `all_values.id` column named `id` if it doesn't contain unique values? Does `all_values` have a PK at all? If not, _why not_?

Comment: Your `all_values` table looks like an [**EAV anti-pattern**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios) table - is this the case?

Comment: Please be aware that the entity_value in rules in the third row is set to `true`. Meanwhile in the SQL Fiddle link the third row of EntityValue in MyRules is to `false`. And I would apprechiate if you could elaborate a bit more of how the preferrably output should be calculateted since I tried a bit around but for the second rule ("abc" and "false") I get 100 and 102 instead of the "101" and "102" that you suggested in your preferred output.

Comment: @Dai The datatype of entity_value is string. We use SQL Server 2018.

Comment: We are not following an antipattern. I have given a very simplified view of our tables.

Comment: Let me put it another way. The rules table has a combination that is not allowed. all_values table has values that each bucket (In this case the id. 100/101/102) has. Now, we want to find out the bucket combinations that would lead to this combination in all_rules table which is not allowed.

Comment: Just to verify the logic: you want to know the `id` values of each possible set of rows in `all_values`, that matches the whole set of rows in `rules`? Then is there any reason you also don't want to return other combinations `100, 101` and `100, 102` which also seem to fit? Is that because `100` can satisfy all rows by itself?

Comment: Your understanding is absolutely right @Charlieface

Comment: Do you need to deal with more than two possible IDs per combination, would there possibly be 3 or more IDs needed to make up a combination? Also on what basis do `101,102` make a correct combination if `xyz` is not present in their rows?